# How do I resolve an apparent hanging update process

Tags: linux, apt, upgrade

I am trying to update an instance on AWS.  I have little familiarity with linux in general.  However, I did run the command on my Ras. Pi first and had no problems.  However this is the second time the process has hung here.  Last time I pressed the enter key, and more lines showed up but eventually I was disconnected and the next time I logged in I was told I had a Zombie process running.  I rebooted and tried apt-get upgrade again and still am confronted with this after a bit of time

Here is the content

```
119 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 3 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/77.0 MB of archives.
After this operation, 8,320 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? Y
E: Version '2.02.66-4ubuntu7.4' for 'libdevmapper1.02.1' was not found
E: Version '2.02.66-4ubuntu7.4' for 'dmsetup' was not found
E: changelog for this version is not (yet) available; try https://launchpad.net/
ubuntu/+source/update-manager/+changelog
E: Version '2.02.66-4ubuntu7.4' for 'libdevmapper-event1.02.1' was not found
Reading changelogs... Done
ca-certificates (20130906) unstable; urgency=low

   Update mozilla/certdata.txt to version 1.86
      Certificates added (+) (none removed):
     + "Actalis Authentication Root CA"
     + "Trustis FPS Root CA"
     + "StartCom Certification Authority" (renewal/rehash)
     + "StartCom Certification Authority G2"
     + "Buypass Class 2 Root CA"
     + "Buypass Class 3 Root CA"
/tmp/tmpEp5oWU
```

Comment: Is there perhaps more than just this in the output? An error or something?

Comment: Thanks for reading I added the rest of the content that preceded the section where it is hanging

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are in a [pager](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminal_pager) program, where you can scroll through the change logs of the packages that you are installing. Ubuntu's default pager (like most unices out there, except some embedded or antique systems which have the more primitive `more`) is [less](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Less_%28Unix%29).

The installation process is not hung: it's waiting for you to read the changes. You can use arrow or page keys to scroll through the file. Pressing <kbd>Space</kbd> goes down by one page and pressing <kbd>Return</kbd> goes down by one line. Eventually you'll get to the `(END)`. You can press <kbd>Q</kbd> at any time to **q**uit.

Once you quit the pager, you'll be asked whether to confirm or cancel the upgrades.

The intent of showing you the change logs is that you can cancel the upgrade if some change looks like it might break your system. This is useful for people who use a bleeding-edge distribution such as Debian unstable — and even there, it is not terribly useful. If you use the stable distribution, you'll only get security and major stability updates which you always should apply as soon as possible.

This behavior is caused by the [apt-listchanges](https://packages.debian.org/sid/apt-listchanges) package. You can uninstall the package in your favorite package manager; on the command line, run `apt-get remove apt-listchanges` (e.g. `sudo apt-get remove apt-listchanges` if you use `sudo`).

Answer (score 1):

I think the errors you're seeing are pertaining to APT's changelog facility. You can either disable it or remove it all together.

*1. to disable*

In the file `/etc/apt/listchanges.conf` open it in a text editor and change the `frontend` line to none.

```
[apt]
frontend=none
email_address=root
confirm=0
save_seen=/var/lib/apt/listchanges.db
which=news
```

You can also temporarily do this via a environment variable prior to running the `apt-get ...` command:

```
$ APT_LISTCHANGES_FRONTEND=none
```

*2. to remove*

```
$ sudo apt-get purge apt-listchanges
```

Try either of these and re-running your command to see if that clears things up.

Comment: thanks for taking the imte I am trying right now - using the safe approach first of _disabling_ will report back shortly

Comment: Thanks for your thought but I ended up in the same place

Comment: Actually this might have worked because now when I pressed the enter key after some indeterminate amount of time information about processes continued to update to the screen.  Before it would stop at some point thus thanks

Comment: It did work and I thank you very much for taking the time to answer my question I just wish I understood more but some days you just have to be happy with the results

Comment: it looks like the other answer is right on but yours was useful

Comment: @PyNEwbie - NP. I don't actually use Debian/Ubuntu and was giving you a way to get rid of messages. Gilles A explains the why, which I wasn't aware of either, since I don't use either of these distros.